# Drupal - field_info_field() returns NULL but field exists

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

If I understand correctly `field_info_field` loads field information from cache.

The problem occurs when trying to reach a taxonomy autocomplete for field `abc:def` where `abc`is a field collection and `def` afield inside it.

The url then is: `.../index.php?q=taxonomy/autocomplete/abc%3Adef/search_term`

Drupal returns:

> Taxonomy abc:def not found.

I narrowed down the error to a call of `field_info_field()` which returns Null for `abc:def`, which definitely exists. It just does not seem to be in the cache somehow. Any idea on how to proceed?

I of course cleared the cache, it did not help.

Comment: have you tried `field_info_field('def');`? field collection info will be in `bundles` attribute..

Comment: @VishalKumar Thx I'll look into that when I'm back at work on tuesday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

field_info_field expects a field_name, field collection has no place here

```
field_info_field($field_name)
```

and as a bonus information, the field def instance won't exist in the taxonomy at all, it will exist ONLY in the field collection
so if you need the field instance info, you get it this way:

```
$info = field_info_instances('field_collection_item', 'abc', 'def');
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! If the field collection has nothing to do there, why does the exposed form even submit it?
I managed to get it to work with your answer, which is awesome. But I still wonder why it was necessary to work this out..